# memory mapping a binary file to virtual memory space in linux kernel

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel

I try to understand how linux kernel mmap a bin file to the process's vma. 
I was looking at the kernel code and finally came down to this function

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/sysfs/bin.c?v=3.1;a=arm#L356

attr->mmap is a function pointer, but where is it actually defined?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "binary file"?

Comment: I mean an executable file in elf format.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `sysfs`. Check the implementation of the `mmap` system call.